# Yamaha TF5 USB Output to ProPresenter

Tags: mixer, usb, multichannel

How do I bring in Yamaha TF5 USB channel output (33&34) to ProPresenter (only 16 channels)?
For now, I am having to use FocusRite and it is causing ProPresenter to have a memory leak (crashes after 45 minutes of streaming).  I'm hoping going USB in will fix this problem.
I am using ProPresenter 7.x